# XtraScheduler complex recurrence

Tags: winforms, devexpress, schedule, recurrence

Let's say I have a simple recurrent event
**Do stuff once every 5th day at 3am **

That would be

```
Appointment apt = scheduler.Storage.CreateAppointment(AppointmentType.Pattern);
apt.Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(3);
apt.End = apt.Start.AddMinutes(15);
apt.Subject = "My Subject";
apt.Location = "My Location";
apt.Description = "My Description";
apt.RecurrenceInfo.Type = RecurrenceType.Daily;
apt.RecurrenceInfo.Start = apt.Start;
apt.RecurrenceInfo.Periodicity = 5;
apt.RecurrenceInfo.Range = RecurrenceRange.NoEndDate;
```

Now, I would need a complex recurrent event 
**Do stuff every 6hours every 5th day at 3am **
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to implement with a single pattern event. But you can do it with 2 events. One - every 6 hours and other - every 5th day at 3 am.